# Pro Asp.Net MVC3 - the Apress book by Freeman and Sanderson

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

From "Listing 7-7 Adding an Action Method"
on Page 165 of the book

when I add 
"return View(repository.Products);"
I get
Error:  the property or indexer 'SportsStore.Domain.Abstract.IProductRepository.Products' cannot be used in this context because the get accessor is inaccessible.
And then when I try to run -- I get
"Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' is less accessible than property'SportsStore.Domain.Abstract.IProductRepository.Products'

I am just trying to get to the point in the first section of Chapter 7, where the action method relies on a mock implementation of the repository interface, which generates some simple test data.
Here's my code

```
NinjectControllerFactory.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Ninject;

namespace WebUI.Infrastructure
{
    public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private IKernel ninjectKernel;

        public NinjectControllerFactory()
        {
            ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
            AddBindings();
        }

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext,
            Type controllerType)
        {

            return controllerType == null
                ? null
                : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
        }

        private void AddBindings()
        {
            // put additional bindings here
            // Mock implementation of the IProductRepository Interface
            Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
            mock.Setup(mock => m.Products).Returns(new List<Product> {
                new Product { Name = "Football", Price = 25 },
                new Product { Name = "Surf board", Price = 179 },
                new Product { Name = "Running shoes", Price = 95 }}.AsQueryable());
            ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().ToConstant(mock.Object);
        }

    }

}

Global.asax
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System

.Web.Routing;
using WebUI.Infrastructure;

namespace WebUI
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Product", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
        }
    }
}

Product.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace SportsStore.Domain.Entities

{
    class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
}

IProductRepository.cs
using System.Linq;
using SportsStore.Domain.Entities;



namespace SportsStore.Domain.Abstract
{
    public interface IProductRepository
    {
        IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
    }
}

ProuctController.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SportsStore.Domain.Abstract;

namespace WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Product/

        private IProductRepository repository;

        public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository){

        repository = productRepository;

        }

            public ViewResult List() {
            return View(repository.Products);
           }       
     }


}

List.cshtml
@model IEnumerable<SportsStore.Domain.Entities.Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
}

@foreach (var p in Model)
{
    <div class= "item">
        <h3>@p.Name</h3>
        @p.Description
        <h4>@p.Price.ToString("c")</h4>
    </div>
}

Assemblyinfo.cs
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Domain")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Microsoft")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Domain")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © Microsoft 2011")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]

IProductRepository.cs    
using System.Linq;
using SportsStore.Domain.Entities;



namespace SportsStore.Domain.Abstract
{
    public interface IProductRepository
    {
        IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the majority of us who don't have that book, could you maybe post your code instead?

Comment: Your code posting is missing the implementation of the `IProductRepository` interface. In this implementation class, which is, as said, missing, the property `Products` is most likely missing a `public` marker

Comment: i tried to edit to add the code for the IProductRepository at the end -- ERROR Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<SportsStore.Domain.Entities.Product>' is less accessible than property 'SportsStore.Domain.Abstract.IProductRepository.Products' C:\Users\owner\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SportsStore\Domain\Abstract\IProductRepository.cs 10 29 SportsStore.Domain

Answer (score 4):

Make your Product class **public**.

```
public class Product { 
   blah blah blah 
}
```

Comment: Thanks I had the same issue and it was the missing public!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the book but let's look at what it says - the get accessor is inaccessible.  So is the property public or private? Without the code I'm guessing, but it sure sounds like you're trying to access a property that isn't explicitly marked `public`.

Comment: Yes, that's most likely it, in the class that implements the IProductRepository interface

Comment: Hi, it's hours of work for me and I'm still trying to make sure that the class that implements the IProductRepository interface is explicitly marked public...

Comment: It's probably elementary, but I am foolishly bumping into the same brick wall :) I've now gone forward in the book's same Chap 7 sample app and created a real data table that is bound in the "NinjectControllerFactory" class to the real SQLExpress data repository. But, I still get the same ERROR quoted above. Remember, don't underestimate the ingenuity of fools to botch a foolproof sample app.:)

Answer (score 1):

Access modifiers. Somewhere not specified or private.

IProductRepository must be implemented from IDisposable. Like ObjectContext

Answer (score 1):

They are in different projects. So, in the current project add a reference to the SportsStore.Domain project(right click on the project->add reference->projects tab). You will get visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Good book. It's working for me so far ....
Are you missing the concrete class "EFProductRepository"?

```
using System.Linq;
using SportsStore.Domain.Abstract;
using SportsStore.Domain.Entities;

namespace SportsStore.Domain.Concrete 
{
    public class EFProductRepository : IProductRepository 
    {
        private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

        public IQueryable<Product> Products 
        {
            get { return context.Products; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is still ERROR "Inconsistent accessibility; property type"System.Linq.IQueryable<SportsStore.Domain.Entities.Product>' is less accessible than property "SportsStore.Domain.Abstract.IProductRepository.Products'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same compile issue. I fixed it by setting the Product class as Public.